# how can I redirect urls in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I'm creating short urls that I want to redirect to their corresponding original urls in Salesforce.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need this functionality in site, then there is two ways to do this:

1. Implement your URL Rewriter class
2. When you open your Site settings,
       you can press button "URL Redirect" and manage this functionality.

Comment: I'm able to create automatically short URL using formula fields. "URL Redirect works great but I need this process to be done automatically so my users don't need to do it manually. I guess implementing a URL Rewrite class is the best option? How can I use it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi again, the full documentation of using URL rewriting class you can find on next link: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm

Comment: Just read it and unfortunately Rewriting Only Works for Visualforce Site Pages. Is it possible to automate this process not using VF pages?

Comment: Only for the site. There is no reason to make such updates in Salesforce Sales Cloud.